# Using dplyr to filter a file using an variable from another file

Tags: dplyr

I have two files. I want to extract a row from one file based on a value from the other file

Tried all kinds of ways with no success.All I want to do is extract the appropriate row from one fie so that I can rbind it to the other

Comment: When you ask for help on SO, it is recommended to give reproducible date, code attempts, error codes,... Rather than just asking for a mind reader.

Comment: voted to close because your question isn't answerable in your current state. Add an example, and it'll become clearer